# How can I run a script from an already installed NPM package?

Tags: node.js, npm

Example:

```
npm install my-tools
npm run my-tools tool1
```

This doesn't work - it looks for a "package.json in my current directory. The documentation for "npm run" says:

> If no package name is provided, it will search for a package.json in
>   the current folder

(https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)

So how can I provide a package name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run a script defined in the `package.json` of `my-tools`.  This functionality is not supported as of `npm@2.0.0`.

The reference to `npm run-script` taking a package name is a documentation error; I have created an issue for that on the `npm` issue tracker: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7440

Some alternatives might include:

1. using `npm explore` to temporarily set current directory (etc.) into the package, e.g., `npm explore my-tools -- npm run tool1`
2. publishing `tool1` etc. as `bin` entries in `package.json` instead of as `scripts`; this will make them accessible via the command line
3. depending on your needs, you may find a more heavyweight task runner such as `grunt` is a better approach than `npm` scripts and binaries